# Rails/ Recaptcha - How do I get the Recaptcha to appear only AFTER the submit button has been clicked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I want my recaptcha to appear only after user clicks submit button on the form.

How can I implement this? I am attaching my current implementation below..

**_FORM FILE**

```
<div class="actions">
<%= recaptcha_tags %>
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd say you have to use javascript (jquery, etc.) for that. Your erb tags are already wrapped in a div with the class `actions`. You could simply hide that in the beginning and place a button above/underneath the div and when the user clicks that you hide the button clicked on and show the ´.actions` div...

Comment: how would I implement the 2nd suggestion you have - i.e. hide in the beginning with the actions div? sorry, i am new to rails...

Comment: this has nothing to do with rails, actually... you'd hide it with CSS. Wheter give the `.actions` class a `display: none` generally, or add it with a single `style` attribute to this div. You can also use `visibility: hidden` if you want the space occupied, but not shown...